# Time-trigger Duplicating Triggers Until Quota Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a time-trigger programmed to occur at 8PM every weekday. While the trigger works fine, I notice each time it runs at 8PM, or any time in general, the function called by the trigger is created as a trigger at least 3 times. It does this every time until the trigger quota is reached and errors with executing the time trigger occur.

```
function timetrigger() {
   var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY];
  
   for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('functionname')
  //.forSpreadsheet('')
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(20)
  .onWeekDay(days[i])
  .create();
   }
}
```

With the example, a new time-trigger called 'functionname' is created at least 3 times each time the trigger time occurs. So, today, 3 will be created with the value under 'last run' being '-'.

How do I fix this so I don't have to manually delete all the new time-triggers?

As mentioned, the code works fine, but I manually delete all the created time-triggers some time after the function is automatically executed.

Comment: Always check to be sure that the project does not contain a trigger with that name before creating one.

Comment: Another option is to delete the trigger programmatically before creating a new one.

Comment: @Cooper Just deleted a trigger with the same name that was not programmed. I ran the trigger again and it duplicated itself again.

Comment: So, I noticed it consistently duplicates itself 5 times. Does it have to do with the number of days defined in the days variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function timeBasedFunction(e) { 
  if(e.day-of-week < 6) {
    //put the code you wish to perform here
  }
}

function createTimeBasedTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(tr => tr.getHandlerFunction() == "timeBasedFunction").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("timeBasedFunction").timeBased().atHour(20).create();
  }
}
```

[time based trigger event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)

This way you only need one trigger and just let it run as long as you wish.  If you wish you can create the trigger manually just once in which case second part is not needed.

Comment: Hmm. Tried this and it didn't work. I was looking at this solution https://support.google.com/docs/thread/158567941/script-creates-trigger-even-the-trigger-exists-already-how-can-i-prevent-it?hl=en. This didn't work either unless I'm missing a line of code?

Comment: I had a typo.  This does work I use this method a lot.

Comment: I see. It still hasn't solved my problem. I think the duplication has to do with the days variable and having a trigger set on the programmed time trigger. Should the trigger work on its own?